# ubuntu 18 logitech usb mouse

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, mouse

I've got an Ubuntu 18.04 (laptop) and I used my logitech (K270) wiresless keyboard and mouse. Until now. Doesn't work anymore. No mouse, no keyboard. It seems Ubuntu just forgot them. :(
I tried a Trust wireless mouse, and it works perfectly. (But no keyboard. :( )

I tried:

```
xsetpointer -l
```

If I used the Trust, it shows "Compx 2.4G Receiver" (and xinput too).
If I used the Logitech it shows nothing similar.

I tried the Solaar program, but it didn't start.

Any idea? What can I do?

Comment: Does it work with other computers?

Comment: plug the receiver and hit on a terminal: `dmesg` what is the output?

Comment: Have you checked the batteries?

Comment: - Yes. Batteries checked. Changed, but no effect.

Comment: - Yes. Check other computer (windows). The mouse and keyboard are worked.

Answer (score 1):

So. I started to use them on an other computer (desktop and windows, but is doesn't matter). First it seemd everything ok. Later randomly didn't want to work...
So it seems it's a hardware problem, ruined. I bought a brand new one, it works perfectly on my ubuntu. :)
Thank u for your help and advices.